# ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'-Labels are numeric

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

I am building a Random Forest Classifier for binary classification problem.My labels are all numeric.

```
print labels.unique()
[1 0]

print type(labels)
    <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print labels.shape
(3000,)
```

But when I am fitting the model with Gridsearchcv

```
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', scaler), ('algorithm', algo)])
cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(labels, 5, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
gs = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, cv=cv, scoring='f1')
gs.fit(features, labels)
```

I am getting this error

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'
```

But when I use

```
gs.fit(features, labels.astype(int))
```

It is working fine.Can someone let me know where lies the problem in my labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the type of your labels to list using the [tolist()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) method. Use

```
labels_lst = labels.tolist()
```

Scikit-learn is not able to convert the series to a list of labels automatically.